# Hide UIMenuController in UITextView

Tags: iphone, uitextview, subclass, uigesturerecognizer, uimenucontroller

Subclassed UITextView

Here is h file

```
@interface CTextView : UITextView {
}
@end
```

Here is m file code

```
#import "CTextView.h"
@implementation CTextView


- (BOOL)canBecameFirstResponder {
return NO;
}
@end
```

Here is first UIViewController file in which subclassed UITextview is using

```
#import "First.h"
#import "CTextView.h"


textView = [[[CTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 410)]autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

But still not able to prevent copy select all from UITextView. Please let me know if i am still missing anything or doing wrong.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Now it is working

Here is the code for reference for anyone need it

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender

{    
[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO; //do not display the menu
if (action == @selector(copy:))
{

    return NO;  

}

else  if (action == @selector(selectAll:))
{
    return NO; 

}

[self resignFirstResponder];                      //do not allow the user to selected anything
return NO;

return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Now only problem having is Zooming. Now i have to work on that to disable it from UITextView.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to disable copy:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the user interaction enabled to YES?

Comment: textView.editable = NO; scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES; Have not set anything for user interaction

Comment: textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: then i won't be able to use scrolling function which i require

Comment: em, maybe you need and UILabel but not a textView