# UITextView remove UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have an UITextView which has set all the dataDetectionTypes. I want to remove the UILongPressGestureRecognizer because the action sheet that appears after long press, on a phone number text or a calendar event text, isn't showing correctly. It doesn't present the cancel button so I need to remove the UILongPressGestureRecognizer. Does anybody have an idea?

Do you know why my actionSheet doesn't present the cancel button? Please help!
This issue is reproducible on iOS 5 and 6 and for devices with 3.5 inch display or less

Comment: Try this link for disabling the options : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636880/hide-uimenucontroller-in-uitextview

Comment: It seamns like it's not working

Comment: have you subclassed the uitextfield?

Comment: it is UITextView not UITextField

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to expand on what has been said in the comments above. In order to do this effectively, you're going to want to create a subclass of the UITextView class. Doing so will allow you to implement UIResponder's `canPerformAction:` function, which will allow you to selectively decide which options you want available on the popup. You can modify the below code to allow for any combination of cut/copy/paste/select... that you want, or if you want to prevent the popup all together, simply return `NO` from this function without calling its super implementation.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:) || action == @selector(select:) || action == @selector(selectAll:)) {
        return NO;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Make sure this is done in a subclass though!